# $or operator is not working in mongodb giving unexpected result

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i write a simple command in mongodb javascript console.

```
db.ChatMetaInfo.find({$or : [{receiver:ObjectId("54cdfeb0eee173f724fe414a")},{sender:ObjectId("54cdfeb0eee173f724fe414a")}])
```

but instead of output it is giving me ... three dots on next line.can anyone please tell why $or as you can see in screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mongo shell `...` means that your query has not finished yet.

Use this query:

```
db.ChatMetaInfo.find({$or : [{receiver:ObjectId("54cdfeb0eee173f724fe414a")},{sender:ObjectId("54cdfeb0eee173f724fe414a")}]})
```

U missed the last **`}`** before **`)`**